# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/interactions/internal/Locatable error is returned after browser window is opened on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: java, selenium, ubuntu

i have imported into Ubuntu a project with scripts for automated testing in java which were deveoped on Windows and now when i run these tests an error is returned in terminal like:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/interactions/internal/Locatable
```

I have already tried to change re-setup selenium and it's drivers but nothing helped. 
Are there any ways ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the selenium version (so, the "browser"driver and the browser) in Windows (where the scripts were developed) is the same of the version that you are using in Ubuntu. Or you have to re-adapat your scripts with the version that you are using in Ubuntu.